# How to get the a file URL in OSX with AppleScript or a shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, url, applescript, finder

I try to hack together a Keyboard Maestro shortcut to give me the URL to a file (just like the ones Path Finder outputs).

So far I use the following AppleScript and replace the *spaces* with *%20*:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sel to the selection as text
    set the clipboard to POSIX path of sel
end tell
```

Then I simply append `file://localhost/`.

The problem is when it comes to special characters, for example I got the following folder on my Desktop:

My output: `file://localhost//Users/patte/Desktop/#%20Old%20files`

The correct output should convert the hash: `file://localhost/Users/patte/Desktop/%23%20Old%20files`

---

A solution with AppleScript or Shell script would be great since I'm capable of incorporate this. I also tried `set the clipboard to URL of the first item of (get the selection)` but this hasn't worked for me - maybe I did it wrong.

Another option would be a script that encodes the special characters - I could also work with that, but I'm not sure what to convert into what - else I'd have look for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is lifted almost verbatim from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600685/get-network-address-of-a-file-in-applescript) i.e. leverage python's urllib to quote the string appropriately before adding in the `file://localhost` to the start of the string

```
on path2url(thepath)
    return do shell script "python -c \"import urllib, sys; print (urllib.quote(sys.argv[1]))\" " & quoted form of thepath
end path2url

tell application "Finder"
    set sel to the selection as text
    set the clipboard to "file://localhost" & my path2url(POSIX path of sel)
end tell
```

I've added parentheses around the print in order to make the python script compatible between python 2.x and python 3.

Comment: Thanks @Petesh, it works beautifully. Perhaps one should mention that the default python version should be set to 2.x (because `print` won't work like this in python 3).

Comment: The default python on the mac is 2.x. I'll put a comment in to the answer to that effect

Comment: Thank you very much Petesh. Works splendid.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple AppleScript that will loop through the Finder selection and put the file URLs on the clipboard, in a return-delimited string. It uses mklement's "2-line" code and is useable with Keyboard Maestro:

```
set theOutput to ""

-- Obtain Finder selection and store it in variable "sel".
tell application "Finder" to set sel to get selection as alias list

repeat with x in sel

-- Convert to alias, then determine its file URL and store that in variable "myFileUrl"
tell application "System Events" to set myFileUrl to URL of x

if theOutput = "" then
    set theOutput to myFileUrl
else
    set theOutput to theOutput & return & myFileUrl
end if

end repeat

set the clipboard to theOutput
```

Comment: This solution is the most compatible with the latest OS X versions and possible also with upcoming versions. Thanks for the submission.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more robust and convenient solution (tested on 10.7.4 - don't know when it became available):

```
-- Obtain Finder selection and store it in variable "sel".
set sel to selection of application "Finder"
-- Convert to alias, then determine its file URL and store that in variable "myFileUrl"
tell application "System Events" to set myFileUrl to URL of (sel as alias)
```

Note:

- Example only works if the Finder selection comprises exactly 1 item.
- The `tell application "System Events"` part is essential, as only the System Events dictionary contains the type of alias class that has a `URL` property
- For brevity, the two statements can be combined into one.

Now, let's say you want to create an OS X service that copies the file URLs of the file(s) and/or folder(s) currently selected in Finder to the clipboard:

- Run Automator, choose File > New, and opt to create a new Service.
- Under 'Service receives selected', choose 'files or folders', and for 'in', choose 'Finder.app'
- Add a 'Run AppleScript' action.
- Paste the following AppleScript code:

```
-- Receives the select files/folders from the Finder and copies their file URLs to the clipboard.
-- If the selection comprises more than 1 item, the URLs copied are separated by LF characters.
on run {input, parameters}
    set allUrls to ""
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with f in input
            -- Convert input file/folder to a "System Events" alias...
            set a to f as alias
            -- and determine the value of the "URL" property, which is the file URL.
            set thisUrl to URL of a
            -- Add the file URL to the overall result.
            if length of allUrls is 0 then
                set allUrls to thisUrl
            else
                set allUrls to allUrls & linefeed & thisUrl
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    -- Finally, copy the file URL(s) to the clipboard.
    set the clipboard to allUrls
end run
```

- Save the new service with a descriptive name; e.g., "Copy File URLs to Clipboard"

This will make the new service show up in the context menu when you Control-click items in Finder (depending on the number of defined services, either at the top level of the context menu or in a 'Services' submenu).

If you want to assign a keyboard shortcut to the new service, open System Preferences, go to Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services, and locate your newly created service there. Click near the right edge of the entry and press the desired key combination.

Comment: Thanks mklement - that's a clean and concise approach. I like it and the AppleScript works just fine. Unfortunately and can't get it to work with Keyboard Maestro, so I'll stick with the other one until I figured out why it won't work.

Comment: @pattulus: Thanks; Sounds like you have a working solution. Since I have a need for similar functionality without Keyboard Maestro, I amended my answer with built-in-tools-only instructions for creating an OS X service that will make the functionality appear in the Finder's context menu and can optionallybe invoked with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I just tried the two lines of code again and it works splendid in Keyboard Maestro → Thanks for this concise approach!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you use the **Finder** to get the selection, You don't need ("python" or "System Events") to get the **URL**

Because you can get the URL directly from the Finder

```
tell application "Finder" to URL of item 1 of (get selection)
set the clipboard to the result
```

Comment: What you get with this approach is an **inode**-based file URL (at least on my 10.7.4 machine); e.g., `file:///.file/id=6707292.176`. If I were to guess, this is typically **not** what you want; for instance, if the file is recreated, the URL will no longer work (on the flip side, it will continue to work if the original file is renamed).

Answer (score 0):

The *AppleScript Editor* has evolved to become the *Script Editor* which now provides JavaScript for Automation (JXA) in addition to AppleScript.

The Script Editor via WebKit JavaScriptCore framework provides encodeURI() and decodeUIR(). The encodeURI() and decodeUIR() greatly simplify decoding and encoding Finder URLs.

**Script Editor *Try-Me* Example**

```
var appFinder = Application('Finder')

var url = appFinder.insertionLocation().url()
console.log("encoded : " + url)
console.log("decoded : " + decodeURI(url))

var urlList = appFinder.selection();
for (idx in urlList) {
  console.log("encoded : " + urlList[idx].url())
  console.log("decoded : " + decodeURI(urlList[idx].url()))
}

/*  encoded : file:///Volumes/Some%20HD/%E2%80%A2UnicodeName/file.ext */
/*  decoded : file:///Volumes/Some HD/•UnicodeName/file.ext */
```

NOTE: JavaScript for Automation (JXA) first became available with 10.10 OS X Yosemite.